# How to validate an email address for regular expression inside an Entity class in Symfony2 framework

Tags: php, entity-framework, validation, symfony, symfony-3.1

I tried to validate an email address with regular expression when i submitting form in `Symfony2` Framework. I used `checkMX and checkHost` properties inside `Entity` class. This done. But I could not validate it for regular expression *i.e.* `{,$,#,!,^`.... Please help someone...
Here is my code snippet..

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * product1
 */
class product1
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @var string
     * @Assert\Email(
     *
     *     checkHost= true,
     *     checkMX = true,
     *     message="Invalid email host"
     *
     *
     * )
     * @Assert\Email(
     *     strict=false,
     *     message="invalid"
     * )
     *
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     *
     * @return product1
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Regex.html), you can use this annotation:

```
/**
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *     pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$/",
 *     message="not_valid_email"
 * )
 *
 * @var string
 */
private $email;
```

Answer (score 0):

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Email.html

I think @Assert\Email does the job enough but if you would like to implement additional another bespoke regular expression, you could use Assert tag.

```
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *     pattern = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+$/",
 *     message = "invalid characters"
 * )
```

I know this regular expression is not what you want, but the format used here was not so different from other conventional ones used in any other languages(some characters need to be escaped by backslash), I think.